# Does Scala have a library method to wrap nullable return values in an Option?

Tags: scala

Something like

```
def option[T](v: T): Option[T] = if (v == null) None else Some(v)
```

I'm perfectly happy defining this utility method myself, but just wondered if it already exists somewhere.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
scala> Option(null)
res0: Option[Null] = None

scala> Option(1)
res1: Option[Int] = Some(1)
```

Comment: Not that `Option#apply`  is new in Scala 2.8. Also new is the inverse operation, `Option#orNull`.

Comment: I would also absolutely love this in 2.7.7.  You can roll your own quite easily though.