# Where is the method that boxes an AnyRef into an Option?

Tags: scala, scala-option

In this [blogpost by James Iry](http://james-iry.blogspot.com/2010/08/why-scalas-and-haskells-types-will-save.html), he writes:

> Plus, Scala has an "option" method that promotes a value to either Some(value) or None depending on whether it's null or not ...

I can't seem to find this `option` method anywhere in the scaladoc.

[Iulian Dragos](http://lamp.epfl.ch/~dragos/)'s gdata client project contains a method that is probably what James was referring to.

```
def option[A <: AnyRef](a: A): Option[A] =
  if (a eq null) None else Some(a)
```

Please point out where can I find this method in the scaladoc.

P.S. I have a method that looks like this:

```
def permutations(s: String): List[String] = ...
```

I'm in 2 minds as to whether I should change it to:

```
def permutations(s: Option[String]): List[String] = ...
```

since the client can invoke it with `null`. Currently in the first instance, I expect a String parameter & I box it manually using the `option` method mentioned previously.

Comment: I notice now that this question already has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2105852/does-scala-have-a-library-method-to-wrap-nullable-return-values-in-an-option

Comment: That was an error in my post.  I'll fix it.  As others have written, it's the apply method on Option, so the idiomatic code looks like "Option(s)"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can simply use the apply factory method on its companion object:

```
scala> Option.apply("Test")                
res51: Option[java.lang.String] = Some(Test)

scala> Option.apply(null)  
res52: Option[Null] = None
```

... or the shorter version:

```
scala> Option("Test")  
res49: Option[java.lang.String] = Some(Test)

scala> Option(null)
res50: Option[Null] = None
```

Answer (score 1):

The Scaladoc page is [http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option$.html](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option%24.html).

To navigate to it from the main Option page click on the big "C" in the circle next to the class name at the top of the page.   That toggles between the class and the companion.  You can also navigate to the companion by clicking the "O" in the left nav to the left of the class name.

Comment: That links to the class, not the companion object, and there's no such link.

Comment: Yes, thanks - the $html got left off of the link src.  Fixed.   I've also changed the info about navigating to the companion, the Scaladoc changed and that's not there any more.

Comment: Thanks. Wow, what a useless change to the scaladoc; that is wholly non-obvious :S

Comment: Yeah, I would tend to agree, though the left nav thing is a bit more obvious :)